# What is the minimum number of data points/observations required to use Theil-Sen?

Tags: sample-size, statistical-power, estimators, small-sample, trend

I am working on an algorithm which requires estimating trend magnitudes of data points. I have been told to use Theil-Sen as it is more robust to outliers and it is non-parametric. As users will be able to input their own data, I'm wondering about establishing a warning, telling users when they have too few data points that the power of the estimator might be low, or there may be false detection of trends. I've tried looking for a minimum recommended number of observations, but I can't find anything. I understand for regression generally the recommended minimum is 10 observations per predictor variable, but is it different for Theil-Sen considering it's pairwise, essentially increasing the number of unique slopes? So, how many observations are needed for Theil-Sen?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: This estimator can be computed with as few as two observations with different first coordinates.  The number of observations "needed" will depend on what you might mean by that term.  For instance, it's legitimate to warn about low power, but what do you mean by "low," exactly?  Are you really just trying to ask us indirectly how to compute the power and size of a test for a trend based on the Theil-Sen slope estimate?

Comment: @whuber Thanks for your response. Unfortunately, since the algorithm requires everything to be as 'hands-off' as possible, I really am just looking for a general recommendation or rule of thumb. I.e., at what point would a statistician say they wouldn't trust the Theil-Sen estimator because of the sample size? 5? 10? 20? 

Although, your comment about testing for the power is interesting. It would be helpful if I could incorporate something like that to report back to the user along with the estimated slope.

Comment: IMHO, a responsible statistician would not provide such a blanket answer, knowing that it must depend on the user's acceptable level of estimation error and tolerance of decision risks.

Comment: @whuber Ok... but surely there is a number that you would say, no way in no circumstance?

Comment: I gave it originally: two is the minimum.  If I thought the responses at two different times were accurate and precisely measured, then I -- along with billions of people before me -- would be perfectly happy to use those two points to estimate the average rate of change between those two times.  That's the Theil-Sen estimator.